# Django Rest Framework: How to use EXCEPTION_HANDLER with DEBUG = True?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using a custom exception handler for my REST API, which responds with JSON data that my front end knows how to handle. The problem is that with the setting `DEBUG = True`, Django doesn't use my custom exception handler. Instead, it responds with the standard HTML debug page, like this:

[image: Here's the default response with DEBUG = True]

Here's my `settings.py`:

```py
DEBUG = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   # This doesn't seem to do anything when DEBUG == True
   'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'stripe_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
...
```

I know that I could just set `DEBUG = False`, but if I did that I'd also have to change many other things that use the `DEBUG` variable.

**So, How can I use my custom exception handler with the `DEBUG = True` setting?**

I've already looked for answers in the DRF docs:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#exception_handler

and the Django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#debug

but I can't find the answer I'm looking for.

#### EDIT

I just realized that I forgot to set the following in my root `urls.py`, per the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#generic-error-views):

```py
handler400 = 'stripe_app.views.bad_request'
handler500 = 'stripe_app.views.server_error'
```

However, `DEBUG = True` still causes problems. For example, even if I created a view like this:

```py
def always_raise_exception(request):
    raise Exception
```

If `DEBUG == True`, the above view responds with the standard Django HTML debug page.

If `DEBUG == False`, it responds (correctly) with a JSON response (another edit: I think this is just because the server server raised a different exception than with `DEBUG = True`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that with `DEBUG=False`, exception handler is being used?

From the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling):

> Note that the exception handler will only be called for responses generated by raised exceptions. It will not be used for any responses returned directly by the view, such as the HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST responses that are returned by the generic views when serializer validation fails.

From your example, I guess you didn't explicitly raise 404, so exception handler is avoided.

Comment: I think you are right. Setting `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` in `settings.py` still gives me properly formatted responses for validation errors. I was hoping I could find an easy way to format *all* of my error responses in a certain way. Thanks for your help.